# Find out sigabrt message

Tags: swift, alamofire, sigabrt

After xcode update my api methods stop work. I can't even see error message. I got this:

[image]

What i want is, to see something like usually typed in console:
Programm terminated due to uncaught exception.. etc. But i can't understand what error is and how to fix it. How to print out error message?

After i click on "next" breakpoint button, programm just exit and still there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with SIGABRTs I go to the top of the error message in console to actually find out the error.

Comment: but i got noone, i posted a screenshot.

Comment: Do you know what caused the error initially? If so try to cause that to happen again and see if you get an error message